# submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build - iOS app Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, crashlytics

I use `Crashlytics` and `Jenkins`. 
I have some problem when upload app in crashlytics.

Jenkins Response:

```
+ /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/app.dev/Crashlytics.framework/submit **************c******* *****************92******** -ipaPath /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/app.dev/build/app.ipa -emails -notesPath -groupAliases $'\357\273\277Testers'
2015-02-24 17:27:33.561 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.1 (11)
2015-02-24 17:27:39.178 submit Crashlytics: Added Testers/Groups Successfully 200
2015-02-24 17:27:56.209 submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build. Response code: 0
2015-02-24 17:27:56.260 submit Crashlytics: Failed to upload binary
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...

[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

On debug: YES

```
Started by user admin
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on imac-ci in workspace /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/ios.appname.dev
[ios.appname.dev] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/63/lzs96szn2qd3pwl9tb9vdfbh0000gr/T/hudson6206241710756313385.sh
+ /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/ios.appname.dev/Crashlytics.framework/submit c***************40 0c*****************d -ipaPath /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/ios.appname.dev/build/appname-1.0-6168.ipa -groupAliases testers -debug YES
2015-02-25 15:14:57.161 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.1 (11)
2015-02-25 15:14:57.166 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: /Users/jenkins/node/workspace/ios.appname.dev/build/appname-1.0-6168.ipa
2015-02-25 15:14:57.501 submit Crashlytics: Path To App: /var/folders/63/lzs96szn2qd3pwl9tb9vdfbh0000gr/T/appname-1.0-6168/Payload/appname.app
2015-02-25 15:15:01.139 submit Crashlytics: Added Testers/Groups Successfully 200
2015-02-25 15:15:01.143 submit Crashlytics: Submitting IPA at /var/folders/63/lzs96szn2qd3pwl9tb9vdfbh0000gr/T/com.crashlytics.mac/distributions/086CD7B7-ABCD-4A78-531A-1E9A324591C8.ipa
2015-02-25 15:15:18.160 submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build. Response code: 0
2015-02-25 15:15:18.179 submit Crashlytics: Failed to upload binary
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...

[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics here. Not sure if you stripped the values out or not, but when submitting your .IPA - do you have a value after -emails and -notesPath?

If not, remove those optional parameters and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from my comment, if you have declared one of the optional parameters such as -notesPath or -emails then make sure you also pass in a value or remove the parameter and you'll be all set :)

-Mike from Crashlytics

Comment: The problem arose again, added the question above

Comment: Can you send me a note at support@ so I can do some additional digging on the backend?

Comment: I get "submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build. Response code: 0" now.